# How to escape a block of text from formatting in Atlassian markup

Tags: escaping, markup

I can't find a way to tell the Atlassian markup engine to ignore formatting code within an *inline* portion of text. For example if I write `[_var_ for _var_(*args) in list]` in a Crucible comment, it thinks this is a link with underlines etc.

I'm not interested in escaping (with \) each individual markup character in this block of code; it's error prone and messy. The {noformat} macro creates a block of text (separate paragraph), not inline with surrounding text.

I've searched at length, and the closest I've found is an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16893250/869951) by creating a custom macro. This might work but I don't have admin access to our JIRA, and it seems like this macro would have to be created for all of our Atlassian services (JIRA, Crucible, FishEye, etc).

Is there no other way to do this simple and basic operation of escaping an inline portion of text from the markup engine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are asking for is perfectly reasonable. Sadly, that is not currently a feature of the Atlassian comment editor. The only way to achieve in-line escaping currently is to use the backslash before each special character.

A custom macro, deployed as an atlassian add-on, would give you what you need. You could develop an add-on yourself, using the [Atlassian Software Development Kit (SDK)](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started).

Alternatively, [AppFusions](http://www.appfusions.com) could develop the add-on for you, on a commercial basis. I think you might find that option cost-effective.

Answer (score 1):

For in-line code, you can use double braces, as the [now top rated answer of the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13116392/4144897) suggests. Just recommenting here for completeness.

```
{{[var for var(*args) in list]}}
```

Confluence will render the text as monospaced code once you type in the closing double braces.

Answer (score 0):

Though it may seem an additional functionality, in our project select part of text and press Other('+') -> preformatted