# Confluence Wiki - Preformatted vs Paragraph?

Tags: confluence

I've been told, when editing with Confluence Wiki page, the differences between a *Preformatted* style and a *Paragraph* style is that

- *Preformatted* remain it's style from the origin when it's copy and pasted and *Paragraph* does not.

However when I test it, *Paragraph* does the same thing.  Anyone knows the differences between these two?  I did some googling but doesn't seems to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preformatted text is exactly similar to the Monospace text in Confluence editor when you add a new text in your wiki. (You can manually add monospace text via `{{}}`). As far as I know and you can see in other [Articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104501/how-to-format-an-inline-code-in-confluence), Preformatted introduced after Confluence 4.x.

In the other hand, Paragraph is a normal Paragraph in the editor. I don't know where did you get that answer about their behaviour during copy paste but you can see the difference between Paragraph and Preformatted text as well as similarity between monospace and Preformatted in attached screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, so a preformatted, monospace and paragraph are just 3 different types of text spacing / style?

Comment: Yes I believe so, while preformatted and monospaces are same. Monospace is still using the old style wiki markup {{ method and they kind added it to the list of the formatting as a reformatted. Thus, in fact they are two types of text spacing/style : (monospace/preformated and Paragraph) . hope it helps

Comment: That's the info i am looking for.  Thank you and have a great day!

Comment: No worries you too have a great day :-)